# IDictionary interop C# C++

Tags: c#, c++, com-interop

With CLR Hosting, I'm trying to pass a dictionary parameter to my C# method

```
static public void MyFct(Dictionary<string, string> info) 
{
...
}
```

The C++ part

```
CLSID clsid;
CLSIDFromProgID(L"System.Collections.Hashtable", &clsid);

// dict creation
IDictionaryPtr pHash;
CoCreateInstance(clsid, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, __uuidof(mscorlib::IDictionary), (void **)  &pHash);

variant_t vKey(L"key");
variant_t vValue(L"value");

hr = pHash->Add(vKey, vValue);

variant_t vtHash = static_cast<IUnknown *>(pHash);

// adding it to C# args list
SAFEARRAY* psaStaticMethodArgs = SafeArrayCreateVector(VT_VARIANT, 0, 1);

LONG i = 0;
SafeArrayPutElement(psaStaticMethodArgs, &i, &vtHash);

// adding param to C# method call
// (spType is the pointer to my class)
hr = spType->InvokeMember_3(MyFct,
                            static_cast<BindingFlags>(BindingFlags_InvokeMethod | ...),
                            NULL,
                            vtEmpty,
                            psaStaticMethodArgs,
                            &vtRet);
```

But the call fails
It tells me "Method not found".
This happens when parameter types don't match.

If it is too complex, should I use C++/CLI (I'm not a huge fan of that... stuff) :)

Comment: Fails means????

Comment: Parameters don't match :(

Comment: What is spType?

Comment: `HashTable` implements `IDictionary`, but not `IDictionary<string,string>`. So it does not surprise me that parameters don't match.
Your C# method is also expecting a concrete `Dictionary<string,string>`, not the interface.

Comment: Ok, I understand, Any ideas how to fix that ? :)

Comment: try System.Collections.IDictionary instead of Dictionary<string, string> in C#

Comment: @gnud And it is `Hashtable`, not `HashTable`

Comment: "System.Collections.IDictionary instead of Dictionary<string, string> in C#". Ok but How can I get values on C# side after that ?

Comment: Or simply Hashtable if you want. You just can't use a generic here

Comment: Ok, it works !, thanks for your help. For my own culture, do you think it is possible to do the job with Dictionary ?. Do you know sites that talk about that. The C# interop is so poorly documentated on the net... Thanks again